# IllegalStateException: PsiFile not parsed for filepath/settings.gradle. Wait until onPsiFileAvailable() is called

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea, gradle, android-studio

I get following output in Event Log in Android Studio 0.4.6 after project clean (project does not run).

```
 IllegalStateException: PsiFile not parsed for /filepath/settings.gradle. Wait until onPsiFileAvailable() is called.: PsiFile not parsed for file /filepath/settings.gradle. Wait until onPsiFileAvailable() is called.
```

Has anyone met the problem ?

Comment: The short answer is to ignore it, as it's probably harmless, but what's the full stack trace of the exception?

Comment: There is no stack trace available for me anymore, but if anyone else face that problem could post it under the question. ty

Comment: @ScottBarta No because of this, I can't import my project.

Comment: I'm facing a similar problem:

13:54:14 IllegalStateException: PsiFile not parsed for file /filepath/build.gradle. Wait until onPsiFileAvailable() is called.

Answer (score 1):

Odly i encountered the same issue on Android Studio 1.3.1.

What helped for me was just removing and then reimporting the project.

Answer (score 0):

1、`Copy the content of build.gradle` (拷贝build.gradle文件的内容)
2、`Delete build.gradle`（删除build.gradle）
3、`New a file called build.gradle`（重新新建一个build.gradle文件）
4、`Parse content to build.gradle you just copy`（拷贝刚刚粘贴的内容）
5、`Done`（搞定）